# How to dynamically export variables using __all__ in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary containing a different model name, which each of them I want to import and use in other module (python file).

Currently I am doing unwisely and fixed code way like this:

**a.py**

```
MODELS = { 
            "REGISTER":"model register",
            "REGISTER_UNATH": "model register unauthorised",
            "REGISTER_HISTORY": "model register old record"
         }

# variables to export for use outside
REGISTER         = MODELS['REGISTER']
REGISTER_UNATH   = MODELS['REGISTER_UNATH']
REGISTER_HISTORY = MODELS['REGISTER_HISTORY']

__all__ = ['REGISTER', 'REGISTER_UNATH', 'REGISTER_HISTORY']
```

**b.py**

```
from a import *

print ("Check Model Register")
print (REGISTER)

print ("Check Model Register unauthorised")
print (REGISTER_UNATH)

print ("Check Model Register old record")
print (REGISTER_HISTORY)
```

However, for `a.py` I want to do export variables from MODELS dictionary dynamically as that dictionary will be growing more and more in future.

So, I do something like this but does not work

```
MODELS = { 
            "REGISTER":"model register",
            "REGISTER_UNATH": "model register unauthorised",
            "REGISTER_HISTORY": "model register old record"
         }

# variables to export for use outside

modelist = []

for model, modelDesc in MODELS.items():

    # append to list ready for export
    modelist.append(model)

# export for using outside
__all__ = modelist
```

Then by `python b.py`, I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from a import *
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'REGISTER'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried doing `globals().update(MODELS); __all__ = list(MODELS.keys())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# turn the key-value pairs in `MODELS` into variable-value pairs
globals().update(MODELS)

# record those variable names in `__all__`
__all__ = list(MODELS)
```